# How do you get values from SelectedItem in a multi-column ListView in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listview, linq-to-entities

I have a ListView control as below

### XAML

```
<ListView Name="myListView" MinHeight="200" FontSize="14" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Reference Code" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReferenceCodeDescription}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="594" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"   />
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <VirtualizingStackPanel />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 </ListView>
```

I have populated the ListView control with data using LINQ to Entities.

### Code-Behind

```vb
Dim Stk As New List(Of Stock)
            Dim Ref As New List(Of ReferenceCode)

            Stk = Context.Stocks.ToList
            Ref = Context.ReferenceCodes.ToList

            Dim mySource = From s In Stk
                           Join r In Ref On s.StockID Equals r.StockID
                           Where s.Description.ToLower.Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToLower)
                           Select r.ReferenceCodeDescription, s.Description

            myListView.ItemsSource = mySource
```

My question is how do I get a reference to individal GridViewColumn items from the SelectedItem property of the ListView ?

When I try

```vb
myListView.SelectedItem
```

I get the entire row back (E.g:  {Reference Code = Z88 , Description = OIL FILTER}

I suspect that I am using an Anonymous type as my ItemsSource and that if I used a Named Type I may be able to interrogate the SelectedItem better, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with the properties you need and create instances of that class in the `select` part of the Linq query assigning the properties of the queried object to the properties of your new instance (an example for this [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384607.aspx) as well). If you are going to reuse the created objects outside of the local scope do *not* use anonymous types. Then you can cast the `SelectedItem` to that class and access those properties.

(I do not know if you can do this in vb.net but in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type) a method for casting an anonymous type in C# is given. (Further in C# only you could just make the item [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) and access the properties as you see fit.))

---

**Edit:** C# Example:

```cs
public class MyItem
{
    public string ReferenceCodeDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var items = from r in ItemsA
            join s in ItemsB on r.StockID equals s.StockID
            select new MyItem()
            {
                ReferenceCodeDescription = r.ReferenceCodeDescription,
                Description = s.Description
            };
myListView.ItemsSource = items;
```

```cs
MyItem item = (MyItem)myListView.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(item.Description);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above looks rather verbose - here's another way that I prefer due to it's simplicity...

*If attempting to access it in the `xaml.vb` code:*

```
dim myItem as DataRowView = myListView.SelectedItem
dim myColumn1 as String = myItem.Row.Item(0)
dim myColumn2 as Date = myItem.Row.Item(1)
etc.
```

*If accessing it in the `ViewModel.vb`*, create a property for the `DataRowView`, and in the xaml, bind the `SelectedItem` to your Data Row View property.  The columns in the row can then be accessed as above.

Answer (score 0):

For all you endangered-species VB programmers (like me) I have converted H.B's solution to VB!

```vb
Public Class MyItem
    Public Property ReferenceCodeDescription() As String
        Get
            Return m_ReferenceCodeDescription
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_ReferenceCodeDescription = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ReferenceCodeDescription As String
    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return m_Description
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Description = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Description As String
End Class
```

---

```vb
Dim mySource = From r In Ref
               Join s In Stk On r.StockID Equals s.StockID
               Select New MyItem With { _
                      .ReferenceCodeDescription = r.ReferenceCodeDescription,
                      .Description = s.Description }

    myListView.ItemsSource = mySource
```

---

```vb
Dim item As MyItem = DirectCast(myListView.SelectedItem, MyItem)
MessageBox.Show(item.Description)
```

### Thanks to H.B.