# make or declare ObservableCollection<a> variable global where a=anonymous type

Tags: c#, observablecollection, datacontext

I want to set the listview datacontext equal to an observable collection so that changes to the collection may reflect on my listview. I create the observable collection as:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumeration)
{
     return new ObservableCollection<T>(enumeration);
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

           Entities.DatabaseModel m = new Entities.DatabaseModel();
           var q = from t in m.TimeSheet                            
                    join emp in m.Employees on t.idEmployee equals emp.id
                    where emp.id == CurrentEmploye.id
                    select new
                    {
                        firstName = emp.firstName,
                        lastName = emp.lastName,
                        position = emp.position,
                        clockInDate = t.clockInDate,
                        clockOutDate = t.clockOutDate,
                    };
           // here I create the observablecollection!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
           listView1.DataContext = ToObservableCollection(q); 
}
```

now my problem is that if I want to add items to the ObservableCollection how can I do that? If I do listView1.DataContext.Add(  that will result on an error.

In other words I have the method

```
    private void btnClockIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // I will like to add items to the observable collection in here
```

---

This is what I have tried and it does not work:

```
    dynamic collection; 


private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       // CurrentEmploye some employee
       Entities.DatabaseModel m = new Entities.DatabaseModel();
       var q = from t in m.TimeSheet                            
                join emp in m.Employees on t.idEmployee equals emp.id
                where emp.id == CurrentEmploye.id
                select new
                {
                    firstName = emp.firstName,
                    lastName = emp.lastName,
                    position = emp.position,
                    clockInDate = t.clockInDate,
                    clockOutDate = t.clockOutDate,
                };

       collection = ToObservableCollection(q); 
 }


    private void btnClockIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

         collection.Add(new
                {
                    firstName = "Antonio",
                    lastName = "Nam",
                    position = "Amin",
                    clockInDate = DateTime.Now,
                    clockOutDate = DateTime.Now
                });
```

Comment: do you absolutely need this to be an anonymous type? Will the query ever return different fields than the ones you specified?

Comment: You are right I was just trying to save time because I need this functionality in some other places but I probably ended up wasting more time..

Comment: You have some options, using a named type is just the quickest. I'll post an answer with more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'trick' it by using a similar 'template' anonymous variable...
e.g. code method would be something like...

```
static ObservableCollection<T> CastToEnumerable<T>(this T template, object value)
{
    return (ObservableCollection<T>)value;
}
```

...and use it something like this...

```
var list = new
{
    firstName = "",
    lastName = "",
    position = "",
    clockInDate = DateTime.MinValue,
    clockOutDate = DateTime.MinValue
}.CastToEnumerable(context);
foreach (var value in list)
{ 
}
```

...it's still recommendable to have a normal named class for your purpose.
You can find more info about similar problem here...
[Cast to Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type)
(Basically you cannot return anonymous type - short of tricks like this - 'inferring' of the type is what's behind this).

Comment: didn't realize you could add extension methods to generic types, that's awesome.

Comment: you can do pretty much anything you can with static methods (and you can make methods generic the same as classes) - just add 'this' for the first param - a bit simplified though.

Answer (score 1):

Using anonymous types in places where you cannot use type inference is not possible, so you cannot, for example, declare a class field or property of an anonymous type. However, there are non-obvious was to use type inference that lets you share anonymous objects across methods.

As I mentioned in my comment, your easiest option is to just use a named type; this will allow you to define the `ObservableCollection<>` as a class-level variable, or typecast your `DataContext` elsewhere in your class.

Depending on how frequently you need  to use this code, there is a second option that involves typecasting `object` to your anonymous type. This requires you to know, in each place where you want to use your anonymous type, what fields it has ***in what order***. It also requires that every use of the anonymous type exist ***in the same assembly*** -- this guarantees that the compiler unifies the anonymous types into a single underlying type.

If that matches your requirement, you can use a "trick" like this:

```
ObservableCollection<T> Cast<T>(object obj, T typedobj)
{
  return (ObservableCollection<T>)obj;
}

private void btnClockIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var temp = new 
  { 
    firstName = string.Empty, 
    lastName = string.Empty, 
    position = string.Empty, 
    clockInDate = DateTime.Min, 
    clockOutDate = DateTime.Now 
  };

  var collection = Cast(lstView1.DataContext, temp);
  collection.Add(...);
}
```

Let me repeat, this is a somewhat messy "trick" that takes advantage of an obscure detail of how C# implements anonymous types. It's not a "hack" per-se, since the behavior is guaranteed by the spec, but there severe limitation to how far this works. If you only have one or two such collections, I would definitely lean towards giving your types names.

Comment: the method: `ObservableCollection<T> Cast<T>(object obj, T typedobj)` gives me a compilation error saying: `Cannot convert type 'T' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: yeah, typo in my answer, sorry. typecast the wrong parameter. fixed now.

Comment: though I like the extension method version a tiny bit better :)

Comment: just a matter of style:) (I wouldn't have posted my answer just for that, but we posted almost at the same time) - this is still a 'hack' no matter how we put it, more of a fun coding

Comment: I dunno; the fact that the C# spec explicitly makes a guarantee that this will work makes me more likely to use it than, say, relying on the implementation of GetHashCode()