# Using Anonymous type in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to use an anonymous type as source to a GridView. But it will be filtered first using a dropdownlist. Let me explain: I have a type I defined as follows:

```
    IEnumerable<object> data = new[]{
    new{Name="McClure Wallace", Id=1, Sal=10000d, Age=29}, 
    new{Name="John Jones", Id=2, Sal=12000d, Age=27}, 
    new{Name="Gloria Flowhart", Id=3,Sal=14000d, Age=21}
            . . .
    };
```

I use this as source to a dropdownlist:

```
    ddlEmployee.DataSource=data;
    ddlEmployee.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlEmployee.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddlEmployee.DataBind();
```

When the user selects an item from the list I want to get the corresponding object and bind it in a Gridview:

```
    var sel = ddlEmployee.SelectedItem.ToString();

   var selData = from d in data where **d.Id= sel** select d;
   gvSearchResults.DataSource = selData;
   gvSearchResults.DataBind();
```

But the problem is that since I will get d as an object, it throws an error on d.Id.

How can I fix this. Please note that I may not be able to change definition of 'data' as this is controlled outside the app. I am only showing here for clarity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `Enumerable<object>`. When you do your LINQ query it will say that `Id` is not part of `object`

Try this instead

```
var data = new[]{
new{Name="McClure Wallace", Id=1, Sal=10000d, Age=29}, 
new{Name="John Jones", Id=2, Sal=12000d, Age=27}, 
new{Name="Gloria Flowhart", Id=3,Sal=14000d, Age=21}
        . . .
};
```

Also, I don't know if `d.Id= sel` is exaclty what you have (except for the `*`). If that's the case you need to change a couple of things

1) `sel` is a `string` so you need to convert it to `int`

2) you need to use `==` to compare

Comment: Perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I have another question related to this: Can I pass and retrieve the "data" through a Session Object? What should I use for casting?

Comment: @Rupesh Saini: that's a little more complicated and not very recommended, a defined type is prefered for this case. You might be able to do it using something called "cast by example". see this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type

Answer (score 1):

You can use "dynamic" data type, so something like this works:

```
        dynamic data = new[]{
           new{Name="McClure Wallace", Id=1, Sal=10000d, Age=29}, 
           new{Name="John Jones", Id=2, Sal=12000d, Age=27}, 
           new{Name="Gloria Flowhart", Id=3,Sal=14000d, Age=21}
        };

        Console.WriteLine(data[0].Name);
```

Would this help you?

Comment: same comment as for jadarnel27. Stuck with 3.5 :(

Comment: @RupeshSaini, upgrade as soon as possible, you're missing fancy stuff there :) 4.5 almost here as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, you want `sel` to be the `SelectedValue`, not the `SelectedItem` (so that you get the `id` property for your `where` clause).  You also want it to be an int, so that you can compare it to the `id` in your LINQ query:

```
int sel = int.Parse(ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
```

Next, you can set your `IEnumerable` as a `dynamic` typed object, to avoid the compiler errors you mentioned:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> data = new[]{
                                    new{Name="McClure Wallace", Id=1, Sal=10000d, Age=29}, 
                                    new{Name="John Jones", Id=2, Sal=12000d, Age=27}, 
                                    new{Name="Gloria Flowhart", Id=3,Sal=14000d, Age=21}
                                };
```

Finally ([as Caludio said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931803/)), you do want to use the `==` operator in your LINQ query:

```
var selData = from d in data where d.Id == sel select d;
```

At this point, your `DataBind()` should run with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I am struck with 3.5 so I cant try your solution but I am sure it works so +1 for you

Comment: @RupeshSaini Ah, I always forget `dynamic` is a 4.0 feature.  Good luck, I'm glad you were able to get some help!