# Filtering an ICollectionView with an anonymous type but needs Predicate<object>?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an ICollectionView built from a LINQ to Entities query comprised of an anonymous object ...I want to apply filter to this collection, however the Filter property expects a Predicate

What can I do in order to apply the filter on this anonymously typed collection?

```
var playerDatabase = (from p in NFLDataContext.DimPlayers
                    join c in NFLDataContext.DimColleges on p.CollegeID equals c.CollegeID
                    join pos in NFLDataContext.DimPositions on p.PositionID equals pos.PositionID
                    select new
                    {
                        FirstName = p.FirstName,
                        LastName = p.LastName,
                        FullName = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                        CollegeName = c.CollegeName,
                        CollegeID = p.CollegeID,
                        PositionCode = pos.PositionCode,
                        PositionName = pos.PositionName,
                        PositionID = p.PositionID,
                        PlayerID = p.PlayerID
                    }).ToList();


        dgPlayers.ItemsSource = playerDatabase;
```

Elsewhere in an event handler ....

```
        string SomeFilterCondition;
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgPlayers.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = (item) =>
        {
             ?????????????
        };
```

Comment: Use type inference.  Please show us your code.

Comment: How would I use type inference here when the predicate signature is Object ?

Comment: Simple answer: switch to a real class.

Comment: Umm, yeah but I'm interested in seeing if there's a solution for this general type of problem ..obviously I could define a data payload object but sometimes you don't always have that luxury.

Comment: @blue18hutthutt When would you not have that luxury? I can only think of when you're not creating the anonymous type yourself, but it's created in a different assembly and merely used by yours. But if you want to handle that case, you should mention it in your question, because it changes what answers you can get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about casting it to dynamic? Smth like:

```
var dynamicItem = item as dynamic;
return dynamicItem.FirstName == "Heines";
```

Otherwise you could checkout this answer for casting to an anonymous type - however, as the poster mentions, this probably does not make much sense in most scenarios :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409776/454272

Comment: Great ideas! Realistically I think I would use a strongly-typed class but it's just good to know there IS an option, even if you probably wouldn't use that in production code :)

Answer (score 3):

This should work -

```
view.Filter = (item) =>
        {
             dynamic anyonymousItem = item;
             // Your condition here
             return anyonymousItem.CollegeID == 1;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamc is not the best option here in my opinion. You should create a class which contains your propertys (e.g. Player) and then change your query to `select new Player()`. In the filter you can then check if the object is of type `Player` and cast if necessary.

Like this you don't have to rely on dynamic dispatch and get all of the benefits of static typing (e.g. compile time errors if you write the property name wrong or change its name).