# How to get properties from an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created an object with a boolean property and a collection.

what I do:

I have a method that gets called when on post which in turn calls another method that returns an object. my problem is that I don't get the object properties.

```
public object methodThatReturnsAnObject(string a, string b)   
{
    object data = new {isSaved = false, personsToCredit = ""}

    // perform my code and if all is valid i set values to my object properties and return the object

    data = new {isSaved = valid, personsToCredit = persons }

    return data;    
}
```

My other method:

```
object Information = methodThatReturnsAnObject(string a, string b);
```

whats my problem?
When I debug the `Information` object contains the two properties that I want to get my hands on BUT when I type `Information.isSaved` it says that information does not contain a definition for `isSaved`?

Comment: What `type` is the object?

Comment: @SamLeach: It's an anonymous type.

Comment: @recursive I know, I was implying he return a non-anonymous type.

Comment: Create a type that inherits from object with the 2 properties you need and use instances of that in your code rather than object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are expecting the compiler to know that your object will have those dynamic properties.

This is just your basic object-orientation that you must use properly.

What you need to do is either (1) define a specific class with the two properties and let your method return that class instead, or (2) use `dynamic` instead of `object`.

Example of approach #1:

```
public class UpdateInfo
{
    public bool IsSaved {get; set;}

    ...
}


public UpdateInfo MethodThatReturnsUpdateInfo(string a, string b)
{
    ...
}
```

You should use `dynamic` only in case you cannot use approach #1, but I'd say that in 99.9% of all cases, approach #1 is the way to go.

Comment: If *really* necessary, you could cast the return value to the anonymous type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type.  But I don't see the point.  Much better to define a class or interface.

Comment: Thanks alot @Roy Dictus! im going to go with the dynamic approach this time since its a rather big project and i don't want to add an extra class for this. I learned something new here, thx alot!

Comment: @Ra3IDeN Why do you not want to add a class?  It's safer to do so, as you will get compile time checking of your code.

Comment: @Oliver at this moment it is cuz im lazy and want to get this to work. been at it for a while. I will probably change it later on and use a class but at this moment ill be happy with the dynamic so i can see the result of what im trying to do.