# using var, accessising contents outside scope, possible "cast by example??"

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LinQ inside an if statement. Also defining as `var` since there are a few columns of different types. The problem is that after the if statement, I want to do a `foreach` but since the var result is defined inside the if statement, it is not accessible outside.

After researching the problem I found online someone used "cast by example" to solve this.  But I can't seem to understand how it works, nor how to adjust it to my actual example.

Here is the cast by example code:

```
static IEnumerable<T> SequenceByExample<T>(T t) { return null; }
```

Below is the main if statement which I will have different LinQ query's inside:

```
if ((currentObject.CurrentAccount == "") && (currentObject.CurrentSector == "All"))
{
    var result = from row in datatableMasterA.AsEnumerable()
                 group row by new
                 {
                     symbol = row.Field<string>("BloombergSymbol"),
                     desc  = row.Field<string>("Description")
                 }
                 into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     symbol = (string)grp.Key.symbol,
                     desc = (string)grp.Key.desc,
                     delta = grp.Where(x => x.Field<string>("TD_Indicator") == "P").Select(r => r.Field<decimal>("Delta")).FirstOrDefault(),
                     prevQty = grp.Where(x => x.Field<string>("TD_Indicator") == "P").Sum(r => r.Field<Int64>("Qty_Net")),
                     prevPl = grp.Where(x => x.Field<string>("TD_Indicator") == "P").Sum(r => r.Field<double>("PL_USD")),
                     topQty = grp.Where(x => x.Field<string>("TD_Indicator") == "T").Sum(r => r.Field<Int64>("Qty_Net")),
                     topPl = grp.Where(x => x.Field<string>("TD_Indicator") == "T").Sum(r => r.Field<double>("PL_USD"))
                };

    CreateDatagridBreakdownPartB(result.ToArray());
}

//portfolio-single sector
else if ((currentObject.CurrentAccount == "") && (currentObject.CurrentSector != "All"))
{
}

//single account-all sectors
else if ((currentObject.CurrentAccount != "") && (currentObject.CurrentSector == "All"))
{
}

//single account-single sector
else if ((currentObject.CurrentAccount != "") && (currentObject.CurrentSector != "All"))
{
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in CreateDataGridBreakdown");
}

 #endregion

//foreach (var x in result)
//{
//}
```

Can someone please assist me in this issue? Much appreciated!

Comment: first of all, you got the *cast by example* code wrong, yours does nothing - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/11/22/t-castbyexample-t-object-o-t-example.aspx

Comment: Does each if statement produce different `select` structures (properties)?

Comment: yes, each if selects different properties

Comment: Dynamic type is your friend then - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx. The *cast by example* trick would only work if your results have a fixed signature.

Comment: @solarissf: So how do you expect your foreach to know the object structure when it gets there? `var` isn't magic, it will always evaluate to a specific type and thus the `foreach` can only expect 1 type, not 4 different ones. If you want to stick with `var` then you need to have 4 `foreach` loops, 1 in each of your `if` statements

Comment: I must have explained it wrong.  the results of the linq will always have the same structure.  for example... string string decimal int64 ....    the only different is adding or changing a where clause to the linq query

Comment: @solarissf: You need more than the same data types, you need the **exact** same object definition. Why don't you just create a class with the properties you want, then you can do: `select new MyClass() { symbol = (string)grp.Key.symbol, \*etc.*\ };`

Comment: If only the where clause is different, then define your base query outside the if/else blocks, then just tack on the relevent where clause e.g. `result = result.Where(...`

Comment: thanks for all the info... based on everyone's comments I realize creating a class was the better option.  thanks for the idea!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast to Anonymous Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend you create a class to hold your data, something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then before your `if` statements, define the list of results:

```
List<MyClass> results;
```

Then in each `if` statement you can `select` like this:

```
results = (from row in datatableMasterA.AsEnumerable()
             group row by new
             {
                 symbol = row.Field<string>("BloombergSymbol"),
                 desc  = row.Field<string>("Description")
             }
             into grp
             select new MyClass()
             {
                 Symbol = (string)grp.Key.symbol,
                 Description = (string)grp.Key.desc,
                 //etc...
            }).ToList();
```

The your `foreach` should be ok...

```
foreach (MyClass x in results)
{
    string symbol = x.Symbol;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the down votes are for, if there is something wrong with my answer then please let me know so it can be amended. It might just be that they are from a couple of people I annoyed on a different question the other day...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type).

The example is here:

```
    void YourMethod()
    {
        var arr = new int[5];

        var anonim = arr.Select(x => new {value1 = "", value2 = "", value3 = "", value4 = 5});

        var anonimAsTemplate = new {value1 = "", value2 = "", value3 = "", value4 = 5};
        var anonimCasted = CastTo(anonim, anonimAsTemplate);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> CastTo<T>(Object value, T targetType)
    {
        // targetType above is just for compiler magic
        // to infer the type to cast x to
        return (IEnumerable<T>)value;
    }
```

But this is **really, really bad idea** to use in life-time applications. Unless, for studying only. Instead, you should use real classes to return from your LINQ statements.

Comment: thanks for the input and pointing out this was not the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your anonymous type is the same in all if clauses and you want to use the *cast by example* trick, described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2007/11/22/t-castbyexample-t-object-o-t-example.aspx), you need to:

Create the extension method like so:

```
public static T SequenceByExample<T>(this object o, T example)
{
    return (IEnumerable<T>) o;
}
```

Change your code to something like so:

```
Object result;
if ((currentObject.CurrentAccount == "")
 && (currentObject.CurrentSector == "All"))
{
    result = from row in datatableMasterA.AsEnumerable()
             group row by new
/* [...] */
```

And then the foreach loop could be done like this:

```
foreach (var item in result.SequenceByExample(new
                                              {
                                                symbol = "",
                                                desc = "",
                                                delta = 0M,
                                                /*...*/
                                              }))
```

Having said that all, seriously consider simply creating your entity type:

```
class MyEntity
{
   public String symbol { get; set; }
   public String desc { get; set; }
   public decimal delta { get; set; }
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, I went with the better idea of creating a new class.  always appreciate finding out the most efficient way!