# Accessing Anonymous Types in C# ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have simple C# ArrayList:

```
 ArrayList sapTestData;
 sapTestData = new ArrayList();
```

and I add elements with:

```
sapTestData.Add(new { Value = loanId, Text = description });
```

Yet when I try to access `sapTestData`, with

```
string test = sapTestData[1].Value;
```

I get a 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value'.... error...

What is problem?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, ever.  Use `List<T>` so that your collection can be statically typed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast to Anonymous Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409734/cast-to-anonymous-type)

Comment: What are you intending to store in you collection? Are they all the same type? Or a mix? Do you have to use an anonymous type? Even a `List<object>` is easier to deal with than `ArrayList`.

Comment: If you really want the list be anonymous, you can try  var sapTestData = new List<dynamic>();

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use generics.

Have an object like this:

```
var Loan = new { Value = “Loan1”, Text = description };
```

Add to list like this:

```
var loanList = GetLoanList(Loan);
```

Access it like below:

```
if(loanList.Any(n => n.Value == "Loan1"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loan 1 is there");
}
```

Have a method like below:

```
public List<T> GetLoanList<T>(T item)
{
    List<T> newLoanList = new List<T>();
    newLoanList.Add(item);
    return newLoanList;
}
```

var is a great feature in C# but sometimes in code like these inference is desirable.

Comment: I would expect `GetLoanList(item)` to return a list with `item` in it.

Comment: yes it returns a list with an item in it..edited the code. thanks.