# How to access a member in a curly bracket { ID: 1, Name: John }

Tags: c#, winforms

I got a variable "StudentInfo" assigned with below value in a curly bracket:

```
var StudentId = StudentBll.GetStudents(false).Select(t => new { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name }).ToList();


            comboStudent.DataSource = StudentId;
            comboStudent.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboStudent.ValueMember = "ID";

var StudentInfo = comboStudent.SelectedItem;
```

The value of var StudentInfo returns as:

```
{ ID: 1, Name: "John" }
    ID: 1
    Name: "John"
```

How can I reference the Name only from the StudentInfo?
For example, 
`lblName.Text = StudentInfo.Name ?`
`lblName.Text = StudentInfo(0).Name ?`
Both doesn't work...

Comment: StudentInfo is just a var variable and it's not a class

Comment: Do you mean `var StudentInfo = new { ID = 1, Name = "John" }`? If so, `StudentInfo.Name` should, and does work.

Comment: Please post your _actual_ code so we can see exactly what the problem is.  Since what you posted isn't complete C#, we're having to guess at what the missing pieces are.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: var StudentId = StudentBll.GetStudents(false).Select(t => new { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name }).ToList();
            

            comboStudent.DataSource = StudentId;
            comboStudent.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboStudent.ValueMember = "ID";

var StudentInfo = comboStudent.SelectedItem;

That's how the var StudentInfo got the { ID: 1, Name: "John" } value

Comment: Please provide it as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53330537/edit) and not as a comment, and also add a tag indicating which UI framework you're using (winforms, wpf, webforms, etc.) as it appears to be relevant to your question.

Comment: Edited, it's WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBox's [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.7.2) property returns `object`. Only at runtime do we know what value this holds. That's why you can't use `StudentInfo.Name` because from the compiler's perspective, you're doing something like `var StudentInfo = new object(); Console.WriteLine(StudentInfo.Name);`: `object` doesn't contain a property `Name`.

Your next issue is that you're using an anonymous type (`new { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name }`) so you can't just cast `SelectedItem` back to the type.

Some options are:

**1. Define a class**

```
public class BasicStudent
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

change your select to `.Select(t => new BasicStudent { ID = t.ID, Name = t.Name })` and then afterwards cast `.SelectedItem`: `Console.WriteLine(((BasicStudent)comboStudent.SelectedItem));`

**2. Use the original class**

Stop selecting an anonymous type and just use the object as-is. Then simply cast back from `.SelectedItem`: `Console.WriteLine(((Student)comboStudent.SelectedItem));`

**3. Use dynamic**

```
dynamic student = comboStudent.SelectedItem;
Console.WriteLine(student.Name.ToString());
```

**4. Use a hacky trick to cast `comboStudent.SelectedItem` back to the anonymous type**

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409776/3181933).

Comment: @ColourShadow - And this excellent answer is why you need to post a [mcve] with your question.