# What is the equivalent of a JPA implementation in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, jpa

I think JPA is nice and convenient ( not to mention standardising, as we used to have every individual programmer doing his/her own thing with a jdbc connection).

I would like to use something like jpa with C# to mysql and sqlserver.

Comment: is this right?  I thought JPA was a specification ?

Comment: Yes, JPA is a specification, along with some concrete classes that allow developers to access their implementation of choice without having to use any implementation-specific code... unless they want to.  Java has a few specs like that.  Other examples include JAXB for XML marshalling/unmarshalling and JAXP for XML transformation, validation, querying, etc.  Useful stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't JPA just a Java ORM?

.NET has many ORM tools, namely

- [ADO Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx)
- [NHibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate)
- [Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/)
- [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

and plus my favourite

- [LightSpeed](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx)

Comment: SubSonic also deserves to be in the list.

Comment: Active Record is Castle Active Record and it sits on top of NHibernate.  FluentNHibernate is another option that sits on top of NHibernate.

Comment: JPA is a specification that an ORM should implement. It is not an ORM in itself.

Comment: This answer is misleading and WRONG! JPA is not an ORM, it is the SPECIFICATION of an ORM, which is VERY different!

Comment: JPA is not an ORM but a specification. There many ORM implementation of JPA such as eclipselink and hibernate implements it.

Answer (score 13):

JPA is just a specification for persistence objects and not its implementation. You can see [npersistence](http://www.npersistence.org/) as equivalent of that on .NET but also you must find an **ORM** that implemented this specification.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the part *"to use something like jpa with C#"* I recommend changing the approach. JPA, as highlighted in comments, is a set of specifications to allow ORM interoperability.

While NPeristence exists, trying to fill the gap between Java and C#, there is no point in using *"yet another JPA"* when industry doesn't adopt it as a standard API.

It's like if you ask for using Java language features in .NET (like "[can I implement an anonymous interface in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface)"). You must live with the fact that a de-facto standard JPA equivalent for C# does not currently exist because 1) there are two major ORM "vendors" (NHibernate and Entity Framework) and 2) EF doesn't adopt NPA.

If you need DB interoperability between MSSQL and MYSQL one of the two open source product above will suffice, but is a whole thing to learn.

My boss said that to learn Java I must start forgetting C#. I suggest you the opposite: clear up your mind, start from scratch, and see that powerful tools are available for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Exist the equivalent for C# and it's called NPA (.NET Persistence API), here some Links:

- [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Persistence_API)
- [NPersistence](http://www.npersistence.org/nhibernate)

Comment: The product is dead and never really gained any traction since its apparent introduction 5 years ago

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework is what you should check out first. It is recommended by Microsoft.

Other popular options include NHibernate or DBLinq.

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET

http://www.nhforge.org (later versions)

http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

Comment: Entity Framework is a Microsoft _product_ so of course it's recommended by them.

Answer (score 1):

.Net Persistence Api is the equivalent in .Net. Both JPA and its .Net counterpart are set of specifications which ORM vendors or open source community can implement. Hibernate is one of those implementation like we have Entity Framework in .Net. When you switch between two ORM frameworks that adhere to JPA, you wouldn't expect any changes in code to accommodate this change as both follow the same underlying specification.