# .NET JPA Specification

Tags: java, .net, jpa

Is this true?

[What is the equivalent of JPA in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756307/what-is-the-equivalent-of-jpa-in-net)

The marked answer shows a bunch of implementations.  My understanding of JPA is that it is a specification?

What would be the equivalent specifications in .NET?

Would it be Linq Providers?  And maybe the connection classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no. ADO.NET is a data-access layer specification (like ODBC and JDBC). Entity Framework is the object persistence framework Microsoft is standardizing on, that would be the closest to the JPA entities. LINQ is the JPQL equivalent.

Comment: So there is no api for the persistence piece ?

Comment: @Nix: There's no *independently-specified* API for alternatives to Entity Framework.  The Java world tends to have more abstractions and opportunities for pluggable implementations than the .NET world does.  Depending on your project, that may or may not be a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET equivalent of JPA is NPA (.Net Persistence API or NPersistence).
see:

http://www.npersistence.org
also see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Persistence_API