# vb.net with Database

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, orm

in java we have this name space "javax.persistence". this namespace allows you to create a data base when you running your application with no necessary to open sqlserver and create a database and table in it it created automatically. is there a name Space in vb.net works the same as "javax.persistence" or not? if yes please write a sample of code as an example to be more specific? thx at all

Comment: I don't know anything about Java at all, but have you seen DomainObjects for .NET? (http://domainobjects.sourceforge.net/) I haven't used it, but it looks like it might do what you want.

Comment: I think this question is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756307/what-is-the-equivalent-of-jpa-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Code First using the Entity Framework? It does require a SQL server but the schema design is driven from your domain model. Scott Gu has a great introduction [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

Comment: If you are just looking for a general ORM (as per the comment on the question) you can use Entity Framework in its default capacity, but if you want to do the actual database design from your code base, I would suggest the Code First feature mentioned above.