# Class Objects to Represent Relational Data

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, orm, relational-database

I'm working on a project to gather data from an external system and bring it into our internal system. Most of our current system uses older technologies (classic ASP), and the project I'm working on requires some newer technology so I'm using VB.Net so I don't have much of an existing .Net foundation to build on.

I have some pretty simple custom classes that I created for this purpose (ex. a Supplier class, Location class, and Product class). These classes were made to temporarily store data from the external system but in a structure that better fits our data structure. Consequently, they are pretty minimal and have only what's needed (ex. they aren't full object representations of each table with all columns).

For the simple independent entities as mentioned above, this isn't a problem. However, where I'm running into problems is when I start trying to relate these independent entities. To accomplish this, I've been using additional classes for each class that inherit KeyedCollection. This keeps data access quick and efficient (ex. I can find things directly by key values without having to iterate through entire collections). For example, my Supplier class has a corresponding Products property of type ProductCollection (that inherits KeyedCollection). This way, Suppliers(150).Products(300) would refer to a supplier with a primary key of 150 and a product with a primary key of 300.

My first problem is this: I want one "copy" of the product with a primary key of 300, and everything else to reference that "copy". This way, when I match up the primary key of the external data with the primary key of our internal data, I can update the Product object once and any/all references will reflect that update.

My next problem is this: with some of the more complicated relations I'm getting to, I'm running into issues with not having the primary key of the link table's record. I need to have Suppliers(150).Locations(33).Products(300) to represent supplier 150 can go to location 33 to get product 300. In the database, this would mean there's a record in a Supplier table with a primary key of 150, and a record in the SupplierLocation table linking supplier 150 to location 33 (note this table has its own primary key, which is not available with the classes/structure I currently have in place - but let's say it's primary key is 1050), and a record in the SupplierLocationProduct table linking SupplierLocation 1050 to product 300 (again, this table has it's own primary key that is not currently known).

What is the best way to accomplish the different things I need, given the scenario? I've looked at ORMs (ex. Entity Framework) but that seems like overkill for the couple of simple classes I need (however maybe doing this all manually is really what's overkill).

Just to recap, I want one "copy" of each independent entity (Supplier, Location, Product), and anything using these entities would simply be a reference back to the original "copy". I also need the primary keys of link table records available. Performance is also an important factor here, but so is maintainability. I don't want to be wasteful (ex. using List.Contains() when I already have primary keys available) but at the same time, I'm not interested in a one-time savings of 100 milliseconds if it means writing my own core functionality (creating hashkeys, testing equality, etc.)

**Additional Background Information**

The purpose of this project is to obtain product availability and pricing information from the supplier, and import it into our internal system. A Location is a place where Products are available, and different Suppliers can obtain Products from the same (or different) Locations. In other words, a Location is not exclusive to a specific Supplier, and a Product is not exclusive to a specific Location or Supplier.

In our internal system, all three of these entities are independent of each other, but are related using link tables. To further complicate things, the Supplier provides this information using two entities, a Ship To and a Product, where the Ship To represents a general source and destination location, and the product represents both the actual product and a more specific source location. For our purposes, we are only interested in the source location and actual product.

Entity examples:

- Supplier provides Ship To "IN TO IN", Product "Widget A - Indianapolis, IN"; we import Supplier "IN", Location "INDY", Product "WID-A"
- Supplier provides Ship To "IN TO OH", Product "Widget B - Indianapolis, IN"; we import Supplier "IN", Location "INDY", Product "WID-B"
- Supplier provides Ship To "IN TO MI", Product "Widget B - Indianapolis, IN"; we ignore this (we already have Supplier "IN", Location "INDY", Product "WID-B")
- Supplier provides Ship To "IN TO MI", Product "Widget B - Gary, IN"; we import Supplier "IN", Location "GARY", Product "WID-B"
- Supplier provides Ship To "OH TO IN", Product "Widget A - Lima, OH"; we import Supplier "OH", Location "LIMA", Product "WID-A"

Comment: OOP was invented to model complex systems in terms of interacting components that encapsulate data, not to model and query data. When used for data modeling, it resembles the network data model, which isn't a good match for relational data. Besides data model differences, you'll also experience other difficult issues like cache invalidation. Instead of reinventing a DBMS in your code, I suggest you design your classes around system responsibilities and sets of data rather than individual rows.

Comment: Your question is both too general and too vague. Beyond our pointing out that the functionality you describe is ORMish and that there are [extant software options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2756316/3404097), which you yourself note, what more specific justified solution choices could you expect? You could start by considering the most lightweight solutions (api to sql) eg NHibernate. The benefit of lightness is that [the more you can push into the database/sql the better](http://thehelsinkideclaration.blogspot.ca/2009/03/start-of-this-blog.html). If an ORM is overkill, give more details why.

Comment: reaanb: I'm not sure you understand what I'm doing, I am using interacting components to encapsulate data. Part of this process involves querying some data from a database, and another obtains it from a web service. I need to take the data from the web service, match it up to some of the data in SQL, then update other data in SQL. My classes are designed around responsibilities and sets of data, however these things are dependent on individual rows of data.

Comment: philipxy: I thought this was pretty specific. I said it seems like an ORM is overkill, however I am not sure whether it is or not. It seems like this is fairly basic stuff: this is three main independent classes/tables that are related to each other, not an entire system/database. Do you feel a lightweight ORM would be the way to go? Would the primary keys of link tables typically be available from an ORM? Would this present issues with things getting cached?

Comment: It just seems like there is a "right way" of doing what I'm trying to do, and I'm not sure it's what I'm currently doing, so my real question is what is that "right way"?

Comment: @akksnv See http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/. IMO, using classes to represent domain entities / tables is the wrong way for an information system, but appropriate for some simulation systems. The right way is to use classes to build services. Suppliers, Locations and Products aren't solution space responsibilities or services. For what purpose do suppliers need to go to locations to find products? For examples, if it's to fill orders, an OrderFiller class might be a better approach.

Comment: @akksnv BTW, when you say your link table "has its own primary key", I assume you mean a surrogate key. Have you investigated using a composite primary key consisting of the entities being associated, e.g. `(supplier_id, location_id)` for your SupplierLocation table?

Comment: @philipxy thanks for the tips, I appreciate it. Could you provide more feedback regarding ORMs and whether or not this particular case would justify the use of one (or be overkill)?

Comment: @reaanb I updated the OP to add additional background information explaining the entities and process a little more. As for the link tables, they each have their own primary key along with two foreign keys to reference the other entities (and some additional columns with other data). For example, SupplierLocation has an ID (PK), SupplierID (FK), LocationID (FK), and some additional columns with other misc. data. Also, these are core tables in our system and unfortunately we couldn't justify changing the types of keys used for this particular project.

Comment: @reaanb given this additional information, could you provide some more feedback/examples on using classes to build services? It seems like this very well could be the answer I'm looking for (ex. a more structural/fundamental change to what I currently have).