# Can an anonymous type inherit from another type?

Tags: c#, .net, anonymous-types, anonymous-class, stringcomparer

According to the MSDN documentation on the [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) property:

> The OrdinalIgnoreCase property actually returns an instance of an anonymous class derived from the [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) class.

Is this a feature I'm unfamiliar with—anonymous types with inheritance? Or by "anonymous class" did the author simply mean "internal class deriving from `StringComparer`, not visible to client code"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a C# anonymous class implement an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the source code for StringComparer, you can see that OrginalIgnoreCase returns an instance of OrdinalComparer, which is derived from StringComparer.

There's nothing 'anonymous' about this that I can see, it's just that it's *internal* so you can't see it from outside the framework.

Comment: Thanks for doing what I was too lazy to do—looking at the actual source ;)

Answer (score 9):

It's not an anonymous type in the normal C# meaning of the term.

It's just a type which is internal, so you don't know the name of it: you can't refer to the exact type within your code.

Comment: Thanks; that's basically what I was wondering. I gave this +1 but accepted Will's answer since he actually went to the trouble of looking at the source code (in Reflector, I'm assuming).

Comment: The source code is downloadable from MS (though their reference source project is a shameful shambles) - I have it indexed by Windows too, so it's very quick to look this sort of stuff up.  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 4):

The *compiler* can create anonymous types that inherit from another type - you cannot.  It's too bad, really as it would be a cool feature to create an anonymous type on the fly that either inherits from another class or implements an interface.

Comment: Yes, creating an anonymous type that implements an interface would be kinda neat.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous type is **anonymous** to us not the CLR and complier. Compiler uses a funny naming which includes <> in the name and only compiler can do that! and **maybe Chuck Norris**...

Comment: Chuck Norris knows the name of the anonymous type.

Comment: Right, but I was unsure if *this* is what the documentation even meant by "anonymous" (the compiler-generated type provided by, e.g., C#'s anonymous types feature). Turns out, from Will's answer, it's just a different meaning altogether.