# Anonymous types based in Interface

Tags: c#

Can I create anonymous implementations of an interface , in a way similar to the way

```
delegate() { // type impl here , but not implementing any interface}
```

Something on the lines of

```
new IInterface() { // interface methods impl here }
```

The situations where I see them to be useful are for specifying method parameters which are interface types, and where creating a class type is too much code.

For example , consider like this :

```
    public void RunTest()
    {
        Cleanup(delegate() { return "hello from anonymous type"; });
    }

    private void Cleanup(GetString obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("str from delegate " + obj());
    }

    delegate string GetString();
```

how would this be achieved if in the above code , the method Cleanup had an interface as a parameter , without writing a class definition ?
( I think Java allows expressions like new Interface() ... )

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard language syntax for that. To *create* an implementation of `IInterface` on the fly you could use Reflection.Emit and maybe something involving generics and/or `Action<...>`/`Func<...>` (with or without `Expression`), but it is a non-trivial amount of work.

Essentially, this is what many of the mocking frameworks do. Look to them, perhaps.

Answer (score 5):

You may take a look at [impromptu-interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface). Allow you to wrap any object with a Duck Typing Interface.

Comment: I'd like to add it really is any object, including dynamic objects and anonymous objects.

Comment: I would like to first understand how this thing works exactly .. +1 for the interesting link

Comment: @Bhaskar it emits a lightweight proxy that uses the DLR to forward invocation to the orignal object. Essential it does the nontrivial work @Marc-Gravell was referring and uses the DLR as glue between the interface and an implementation, dynamic or otherwise.

Comment: @jbtule, exactly. Also I think it's way faster than reflection.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CleanUp(Func<string> obj){
  Console.WriteLine("str from delegate " + obj.Invoke());
}

public void RunTest(){
   Cleanup(() => "hello from anonymous type");
 }
```

- although not really implementing for an Interface...