# c# Is it possible to supply a lambda when an interface is required?

Tags: c#, interface, lambda

In some class method, A, I need to call a library method B, which takes as an `IProgress<Object>` as a parameter.

Normally, I might  either implement `IProgress<Object>` as part of class where A resides, and then pass "this" to method B. Or perhaps I might create a new class whose only purpose is to implement `IProgress<Object>` and handle it correctly-- then in this case I'd create an instance of that class and pass it to B.

But what I really want is to have my implementation of `IProgress<Object>` to appear right inside the method in which I'm calling B, so that there's less of a visual disconnect between the calling code, and the `IProgress<Object>` implementation.  (I consider my implementation of IProgress to be kind of a private, non-shared detail of the calling method and thus I don't want my implementation of `IProgress<Object>` to be in a whole separate method of perhaps a whole other class).

What I've been trying to do is use a lambda in which I will define my short progress handling, and then somehow pass this lambda to B, like this:

```
method in class A {
...
Action<Object> Report = (m) => { // do something useful with m };

B(Report)
}

method B(IProgress<Object> reporter) {
   reporter.Report(some object)
}
```

Of course, I know why this won't work as is - B is wanting an object that implements `IProgress<Object>` and I'm handing it an Action object instead.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve? (IE have my implementation if `IProgress<Object>` appear inside method A?

Comment: C# lambdas are anonymous delegates. What you need is an anonymous type which implements the interface. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface) for some workarounds over the only-public-properties anonymous types that C# provides.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delegates cannot implement interfaces (directly).

Two good options come to mind:

1. Change the definition of the method that you're calling to take a delegate types instead of an `IProgress` type.  (If possible; this would be the preferable option)
2. Create a new type that implements the interface that you need and takes a delegate as a parameter to implement that functionality.

And example of #2, while dependent on the interface, might look something like this:

```
interface IProgress<T>
{
    void doStuff(T param);
}

class LambdaProgress<T> : IProgress<T>
{
    Action<T> action;
    public LambdaProgress(Action<T> action)
    {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void doStuff(T param)
    {
        action(param);
    }
}
```

then you'd be able to do something like:

```
B(new LambdaProgress<Object>(obj => ...));
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't supply a lambda when an interface is required.
But you can supply an anonymous object by using [impromptu-interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface).

This example is from its project page:

```
//Anonymous Class
var anon = new
{
    Prop1 = "Test",
    Prop2 = 42L,
    Prop3 = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Meth1 = Return<bool>.Arguments<int>(it => it > 5)
}

var myInterface = anon.ActLike<IMyInterface>();
```

In your example this can be:

```
A
{
    // Create an anonymous object.
    var anonymous = new
    {
        // Define a method that needs an "object" parameter and returns nothing.
        Report = Return.Arguments<object>(m =>
        {
            // Do whatever you want to do when Report is called.
        })
    }

    // Get your anonymous object as an IProgress<Object>.
    var obj = anonymous.ActLike<IProgress<Object>>

    // Call B.
    B(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `IProgress<object>` interface has just the single `void Report(object)` method, and that you control the API, you could simply redefine the methods that currently require a parameter of type `IProgress<object>` to instead require a new delegate type:

```
public delegate void ProgressReportDelegate(object someObject);
```

Then your example could change to:

```
method in class A {
...
Action<Object> Report = (m) => { // do something useful with m };

B(Report)
}

method B(ProgressReportDelegate reporter) {
   reporter(someObject);
}
```

For more complex interfaces, or where you don't control the API (and so can't change a method to take the delegate rather than on object implementing that interface), this isn't really an option, but it would appear to work in your case.

Answer (score -1):

With .NET 4.5 you can use [Progress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) class

Example:

```
var reporter = new Progress<Object>((m) => {
  // do something useful with m
});

B(reporter);
```

Comment: This answer is correct when the question is actually about `System.IProgress<T>` which isn't explicitly stated, but it is implied.

Answer (score -1):

I believe José is the only valid answer here and helped me with the same problem.

From the question Michael want to call a method "B" but use a lambda instead of implementing the IProgress interface:

```
method B(IProgress<Object> reporter) {
   reporter.Report(some object)
}
```

To do this without creating a new class that needs to implement the IProgress interface, the [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) class can be used as it implements the IProgress interface already. Just create a lambda that looks like this and pass that into your method:

```
var reporter = new Progress<int>((x) => 
{
   // call your own methods that use the reported value here
   MyProgressMethod.SetProgress(x);
});
```

And now you can use this in your methods as per question above:

```
B(reporter);
```

Or if you want to do this in one line:

```
B(new Progress<int>((x) => { progress.SetProgress(action, x); }));
```

Comment: This question isn't asking about the .NET `IProgress<T>` interface.  It was asked before that interface event existed.  They're asking about their own custom interface.

Comment: The solution here is to use the new IProgress in combination with the new Progress class rather than rolling your own.

Comment: The problem is how to implement an arbitrary interface using a delegate.  That the one example used to demonstrate the problem happened to be called `IProgress` is irrelevant to the question.  The question did not ask how to update the UI of a desktop application from a background process with the progress of that background task.  You're answering *a different question than the one that was asked*.  Given that their question mentions nothing about marshaling to a UI thread, it's not even clear that your solution is even applicable to the context in which they're reporting progress.