# Creating an instance of a interface in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I am using an interface in C# and rather than write an entirely new class which implements that interface is it possible to just create an object which implements that interface? The interface is defined as

```
public interface ITokenStore
{

    IToken CreateRequestToken(IOAuthContext context);


    IToken CreateAccessToken(IOAuthContext context);
}
```

And I know in java I could something like

```
ITokenStore tokenStore = new ITokenStore()
    {
        IToken CreateRequestToken(IOAuthContext context) {
            IToken requestToken = null;

            return requestToken;
        }

        IToken CreateAccessToken(IOAuthToken context) {
            IToken accessToken = null;

            return accessToken;
        }
    };
```

Is there an equivalent way to instantiate in instance of an interface in c#?

Comment: Java is still creating a class behind-the-scenes, it's just syntactic sugar - and in a way, their solution to a lack of delegates/function pointers.

Comment: With a mocking framework you can create an instance, for example `new Mock<ITokenStore>()`. You might want to setup concrete implementations of the methods which the mocking framework might do from a delegate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C# equivalent of this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581737/is-there-a-c-sharp-equivalent-of-this)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to "Create an instance of a interface in c#" is to create an instance of a type implementing the interface.

Comment: It will be compiled as a anonymous class.

Comment: No, you cannot do this in .NET/C#, and to be clear, *you can't do it in Java either*. What the compiler does in Java is to build the anonymous type for you, a *type implementing the interface*. So Java has a shortcut to getting that type, C# doesn't.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen While `C#` _may not_, MS's `C#` compiler _does_: see oakio's answer below. It's just not part of any spec (and its use is limited at best), so it's really not a good idea to use.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces have no logic in them by design.  They simply don't actually do anything.

Instantiating one without an implementing class doesn't even make sense

Answer (score 4):

If you really want this:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFoo foo = new IFoo(); // <- interface
        foo.Print();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    [ComImport, Guid("A7D5E89D-8FBD-44B7-A300-21FAB4833C00"), CoClass(typeof(Foo))]
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Print();
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }
```

But if you open compiled assembly on `ildasm.exe`, you will see:

`IL_0001:  newobj     instance void TestApp.Program/Foo::.ctor()`

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know .NET does not have the Java concept of anonymous inner classes. There is a typical need for dynamic implementations of an interface in unit testing scenarios. So may be a look on some dynamic mocking frameworks may be interesting for you, for instance

1. [Impromptu Interface](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) (includes support for *dynamic*)
2. [Moq](https://code.google.com/p/moq/)

Have a look on NuGet gallery for packages tagged with *mocking*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of an interface in C#. You must create an instance of a class/type that implements that interface.

Might want to go read up on [interfaces in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/ms173156.aspx). There's no way to "fake" it like Java does.

I'm kind if intrigued by this concept though since it is something available in another language. I suppose you could use an anonymous class with delegate parameters if your consumer knew how to fake [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). But that hardly seems worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class MyTokenStore: ITokenStore
{
    public IToken CreateRequestToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        ...some code here...
    }
    public IToken CreateAccessToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        ...some code here...
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
ITokenStore x = new MyTokenStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, no, this is not possible.

However, you could write one generalized class that has delegates for each method. Something like the following:

```
public class DelegateTokenStore : ITokenStore
{
    public delegate IToken TokenCreator(IOAuthContext context);
    public TokenCreator RequestTokenCreator { get; set; }
    public TokenCreator AccessTokenCreator { get; set; }

    public IToken CreateRequestToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        return RequestTokenCreator(context);
    }

    public IToken CreateAccessToken(IOAuthContext context)
    {
        return AccessTokenCreator(context);
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
ITokenStore tokenStore = new DelegateTokenStore()
{
    RequestTokenCreator = (context) =>
    {
        IToken requestToken = null;
        return requestToken;
    },
    AccessTokenCreator = (context) =>
    {
        IToken accessToken = null;
        return accessToken;
    },
};
```

I'm not saying it's necessarily a good idea to take this approach. Like anything, the appropriateness depends on your use case.