# How we can use inner anonymous for c# interface?

Tags: c#, java

I am using converting one program of Java into C# in which I am having some problem of using interface anonymous. Please tell me how can I achieve this in C#
**This is example in java, how can we write inner anonymous for C#?**

```
interface Test
{
    public void wish();
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t=new Test()
        {
            public void wish()
            {
                System.out.println("output: hello how r u");
            }
        };
        t.wish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Only for info. Usually Interfaces starts with letter I, in this example ITest. It´s a good way to know which ones are interfaces. Amit answered your question pretty well! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an instance of a interface in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708528/creating-an-instance-of-a-interface-in-c-sharp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a C# equivalent of this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581737/is-there-a-c-sharp-equivalent-of-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an interface in C#. Anonymous types in C# are basically just sets of properties, so they cannot have methods defined in them and they can't implement interfaces.

You could make a class implementing an interface, have an `Action` field inside of it, and assign the method you want to call to that field, something like this:

```
using System;

public interface ITest
{
    void Wish();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    private readonly Action _wishAction;

    public Test(Action wish)
    {
        _wishAction = wish;
    }

    public void Wish()
    {
        _wishAction();
    }
}

class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test(() => Console.WriteLine("output: hello how r u"));
        t.Wish();
    }  
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use a lambda:

```
class Program
{ 
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Action wish = () => Console.WriteLine("output: hello how r u");
        wish();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public interface Test  
{  
    public void wish();  
}  
class Main  : Test
{  
    public void wish(){
    //Your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `implement` the `Test` interface in another class say, `MyTest`. Then just need to instantiate the `MyTest` class and assign it to the instance of `Test` instance. See the following code:

```
interface Test  
{  
    void wish();  
}

class MyTest : Test
{  
    public void wish()
    {  
        System.out.println("output: hello how r u");  
    }  
}

static class Program
{  
    [STAThread]
    static void main()  
    {  
        Test t=new MyTest();  
        t.wish();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anonymous classes the same way in C# as in Java.

The C# way to do the above would've been to use a delegate instead of an interface:

```
public delegate void Wisher();

class Main  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        Wisher t = () => Console.WriteLine("output: hello how r u");  
        t();
    }  
}
```

Depending on your use case you might use the `System.Action` delegate type instead of a custom delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, C# [doesn't allow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface) anonymous classes to implement interfaces in the same way [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5848516/314291)

i.e. The java code:

```
Test t = new Test(){
    public void wish(){ ...
}
```

Would be 'pseudo C#' equivalent to

```
ITest t = new /* AnonClass : */ ITest 
{
     public void wish()
     { ...
     }
}
```

Which of course won't compile.

As others have mentioned, you'll need to implement the interface on a named class and instantiate that, instead (Although implementing the interface directly on `Main` wouldn't be my first choice, either. On a nested class perhaps?).

Comment: sorry but any of the solution above mentioned won't work as there are diff implementation for wish method in different classes when I implement the interface "Test". Any way I am trying to work out this with delegates or lambda expressions.

Comment: Yes, so each different anonymous class implementation would need to have its own (named) class which implements `ITest`. If wish is the ONLY method on the interface, and if the anonymous class doesn't require state in between calls to the method, as you say, a Lambda implementation would be a good conversion.