# Converting an unknown class to a new class having specified interface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, anonymous-types, expandoobject

I need to create a function that takes a List and 2 property names of T and return a list meeting the requirements of a specified interface plus any other properties of T.

Eg.

```
interface ITest
{
  int ID {get;set};
  int ParentID {get;set;};
}
```

Consumer has any class that is convertible into this interface but with potentially different properties than is required by the interface:

```
public class ConsumingClass
{
  public int ConsumingClassID {get;set;
  public int ConsumingClassParentID {get;set;}
  public string namex {get;set;}
  public string namey {get;set;}
}
```

So the consumer needs to get an object that meets the requirements of the interface, so he wants to call a function such as:

```
List<ITest> getnewlist = ConvertList<ConsumingClass>(consuminglist, "ConsumingClassID", "ConsumingClassParentID");
```

The signature of the method would look like this:

```
public List<ITest> ConvertList<T>(List<T> ListBeingConverted, string IDAlias, string ParentIDAlias)
{
    //code needs to return a list meeting ITest requirements plus any other properties contained in T
}
```

Edit: I modified the signature to more appropriately reflect what I'm looking to return.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Why just not inherit `ConsumingClass` from `ITest`?????

Comment: 1. ITest<T> or List<ITest<T>>? 2. Need string names? Yes: reflection would be needed, No: Delegates or LINQ/Lambdas could be used.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek the question is what code can I add to solve my problem?  I want to return a new List object conforming to my ITest interface regardless of what T looks like. I'm thinking anonymous types or ExpandoObjects.  Clearly reflection is required.

Comment: @Tony, I could do this but then I'd have to do this for every class I want to convert, which defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish: which is to create a method to convert a list of objects having certain properties to a list of objects meeting the interface criteria

Answer (score 1):

Derive from `ITest` to create a class that adapts an instance of `ConsumingClass` to conform to the `ITest` interface:

```
class AnyObjectAsITest : ITest {
 public object Object;
 public string PropertyName;

 public int ID {
  get {
   return (int)Object.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(Object, null);
  }
 }
 //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite seeing this but maybe it can be fleshed out...how would I may AnyObjectAsITest contain all of the other properties of Object dynamically?

Comment: You need to implement *all* interface methods. I just implemented one for demonstration purposes. Also, you need to set the two fields.

Comment: Setting the 2 fields, I understand.  How to take namex and namey in my example to new properties called "namex" and "namey" in this class also needs to be done and I don't see that in your code.  Maybe you can show an example of how it would be implemented.

Comment: Well, if the interface does not have those properties, how could a caller access them trough the interface? That's impossible.

Comment: Right, I'm looking for a way to dynamically create a new object meeting the requirements of the interface regardless of the original type details.  By doing this, I could convert any object into a new object having the interface requirements, which will allow me to act on it for view purposes.

Comment: I showed you how to meet the requirements of the interface. I'm not sure I understand how this does not meet your requirements. The interface is implemented and works.

Comment: This link shows a bit what I'm trying to do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-sharp-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface?rq=1